# Query an existing mysql table in database using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an flask app, using flask-slqalchemy to query a mysql database

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/abc'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

there is a table "users" in "abc" database and it is already populated with several hundred rows.
Now i need to import this existing table, rather than first defining it with db.Model
how do i call the table?
if i do this

```
from sqlalchemy import Table
USERS = Table('users', db.metadata,autoload=True, autoload_with=db.engine)
```

then i am not able to make a query like

```
USERS.query.filter_by(done=1).with_entities(USERS.name,USERS.country).paginate(page, 15, False)
```

it generates an error

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'query'
```

because this is sqlchemy command, not flask-sqlchemy, i dont fully understand this.

I have to first define the table USERS like i am creating it for the first time :

```
class USERS(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(500))
    country = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(50))

    def __init__(self, id, name, country):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.country = country

    def __repr__(self):
    return self.id
```

only then i am able to use USERS to query the database through flask-sqlalchemy

How do i access the an existing table users using flask-sqlchemy in an flask app?

Answer (score 1):

In sqlalchemy you should query table(s) with session if you want to query `Table()`. Because `'Table' object has no attribute 'query'`. And you do not need to create table if it has existed, just use it. [sqlalchemy existing database query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955521/sqlalchemy-existing-database-query)

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine()

metadata = MetaData()
test_ = Table('test', metadata,
    Column('msg', String, primary_key=True),
    Column('msg_', String)
)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
print(session.query(test_).filter_by(msg_ = "test").with_entities("msg","msg_").one())
# ('t', 'test')
```

In flask_sqlalchemy, it almost same as sqlalchemy did.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ""
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class test(db.Model):
    msg = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    msg_ = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, msg, msg_):
        self.msg = msg
        self.msg_ = msg_

    def __repr__(self):
        return "msg: {} msg_: {}".format(self.msg,self.msg_)

result = test.query.filter_by(msg_="test").one()
print(result)
print(result.msg,result.msg_)
'''
msg: t msg_: test
t test
'''
```

Comment: i am using flask_sqlalchemy, so i have to define the table and list all its columns and rather than using any binding statement, it will bind it own its own?

Comment: Yes, if you are using class-base. You can try to list part of columns then the error will be raised. And `__init__` is not necessary unless you want to override the constructor([ref](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)).