# Why do I need to define models in a Flask + SQLAlchemy app using an existing database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask and SQLalchemy and I'm currently trying to develop an API connecting to an existing database. I understand models are useful to create a new database, and new tables, but I do not understand what makes it neccesary for me to define models since my tables already exist ?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955521/sqlalchemy-existing-database-query), and I don't understand what makes it necessary to define models if I can simply query my database? Maybe I did not grasp the purpose of models...

Comment: an ORM, like SQLAlchemy represents records from the db in the form of objects. These objects need to corresponds to some class so that they can exhibit entity specific behavior.

Comment: You do not necessarily need to define models explicitly, you could automap/reflect or use core/raw queries.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a model if you use an ORM: because an ORM needs to do the mapping between the database model (the tables) and the object model (the classes).

You don't have to do that if you use a DB-API because you do direct calls to the database. Here is an exemple with SQLite: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html.